# Why am I seeing Parameter Mismatch error in Luminus (Clojure)?

Tags: clojure, luminus, hugsql

Edit (fixed)...

If you are following the [Luminus guestbook tutorial](https://luminusweb.com/docs/guestbook.html) or adapting parts of it, you may come across an error like `Parameter Mismatch: :name parameter data not found.`, and it may not go away, regardless of what parameters you use.  You may find that you are attempting to call a function that does not exist, and that Conman/HugSQL doesn't know what to do with it.

The answer to my question is in the section below:

---

The relevant section of code is in `myapp.routes.home/create-user!`

```
(defn create-user! [{:keys [params]}]
  (if-let [errors (validate-user params)]
    (-> (response/found "/users")
        (assoc :flash (assoc params :errors errors)))
    (do
      (db/create-user!
       (assoc params
              :created_at (java.util.Date.)
              :updated_at (java.util.Date.)
              :pass (generate-password 8)))
      (response/found "/users"))))
```

The code below was incorrect:

```
:pass (generate-password 8)) ; <-- 2 parentheses at the end of line.
       (response/found "/users"))))) ; <-- 5 parentheses at the end of line.
```

I fixed it by changing it as shown below:

```
:pass (generate-password 8))) ; <-- 3 parentheses at the end of line.
       (response/found "/users")))) ; <-- 4 parentheses at the end of line.
```

So it turned out that I was passing the wrong number of arguments to db/create-user! and it seems Conman had no idea how to invoke the query.

Also, I fixed a few things in my migrations in a sloppy way - by editing migrations that had happened.   I have noticed that Conman seems to not notice if you're altering old migrations and queries.sql files.  If you find that queries.sql is not reflecting your DB api (so you are still getting a message about an ID param when you set the id field to auto-increment, then you need to make Conman regenerate your DB API.

This can be done in REPL as follows:

```
user> (ns myapp.db.core)
nil
myapp.db.core> (conman/bind-connection *db* "sql/queries.sql")
```

---

### Original post below

Really simple app I'm putting together based more-or-less on [the Luminus guestbook tutorial](https://luminusweb.com/docs/guestbook.html) and I'm just trying to test the `create-user!` form at http://localhost:3000/users.  Whenever I submit the form, I get some variation of `Parameter Mismatch: :username parameter data not found.`  It's not specific to `:username`.  Whatever params I send, I get `:first_name parameter data not found.` or something similar.

[image: The error page I see]

Here's the expanded params section:
[image: The params it says I'm sending]

I've done a `println` in `myapp.routes.home/create-user!` and I know the params all seem to be there until that point.  I'm not sure how to track it down further.  I'd appreciate any advice on debugging from here, and also if anyone sees something I'm doing wrong, that'd be super helpful.

Stack trace:

```
$ lein run
2020-03-22 16:34:47,244 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider 
2020-03-22 16:34:47,897 [main] INFO  myapp.env - 
-=[myapp started successfully using the development profile]=- 
2020-03-22 16:34:48,471 [main] INFO  luminus.http-server - starting HTTP server on port 3000 
2020-03-22 16:34:48,496 [main] DEBUG io.undertow - starting undertow server io.undertow.Undertow@591ea3da 
2020-03-22 16:34:48,503 [main] INFO  org.xnio - XNIO version 3.3.6.Final 
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.xnio.nio.NioXnio$2 (file:/Users/mattlally/.m2/repository/org/jboss/xnio/xnio-nio/3.3.6.Final/xnio-nio-3.3.6.Final.jar) to constructor sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorProvider()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.xnio.nio.NioXnio$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2020-03-22 16:34:48,616 [main] DEBUG io.undertow - Configuring listener with protocol HTTP for interface 0.0.0.0 and port 3000 
2020-03-22 16:34:48,659 [main] INFO  org.projectodd.wunderboss.web.Web - Registered web context / 
2020-03-22 16:34:48,659 [main] INFO  myapp.nrepl - starting nREPL server on port 7000 
2020-03-22 16:34:48,676 [main] INFO  myapp.core - #'myapp.db.core/*db* started 
2020-03-22 16:34:48,677 [main] INFO  myapp.core - #'myapp.handler/init-app started 
2020-03-22 16:34:48,677 [main] INFO  myapp.core - #'myapp.handler/app-routes started 
2020-03-22 16:34:48,677 [main] INFO  myapp.core - #'myapp.core/http-server started 
2020-03-22 16:34:48,677 [main] INFO  myapp.core - #'myapp.core/repl-server started 
java.lang.Exception: Exception in :create-user!
    at conman.core$try_query$fn__33540$fn__33541.invoke(core.clj:32)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:660)
    at myapp.db.core$eval35973$f__33568__auto____36000.doInvoke(core.clj:13)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
    at myapp.routes.home$create_user_BANG_.invokeStatic(home.clj:46)
    at myapp.routes.home$create_user_BANG_.invoke(home.clj:41)
    at muuntaja.middleware$wrap_params$fn__28296.invoke(middleware.clj:52)
    at muuntaja.middleware$wrap_format$fn__28300.invoke(middleware.clj:73)
    at myapp.middleware$wrap_formats$fn__31491.invoke(middleware.clj:42)
    at ring.middleware.anti_forgery$wrap_anti_forgery$fn__27132.invoke(anti_forgery.clj:94)
    at reitit.ring$ring_handler$fn__38011.invoke(ring.cljc:292)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
    at clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke(AFunction.java:31)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:384)
    at ring.middleware.reload$wrap_reload$fn__24791.invoke(reload.clj:39)
    at selmer.middleware$wrap_error_page$fn__24806.invoke(middleware.clj:18)
    at prone.middleware$wrap_exceptions$fn__25047.invoke(middleware.clj:159)
    at ring.middleware.flash$wrap_flash$fn__28337.invoke(flash.clj:39)
    at immutant.web.internal.undertow$wrap_undertow_session$fn__39192.invoke(undertow.clj:72)
    at ring.middleware.keyword_params$wrap_keyword_params$fn__31059.invoke(keyword_params.clj:53)
    at ring.middleware.nested_params$wrap_nested_params$fn__31117.invoke(nested_params.clj:89)
    at ring.middleware.multipart_params$wrap_multipart_params$fn__31249.invoke(multipart_params.clj:173)
    at ring.middleware.params$wrap_params$fn__31273.invoke(params.clj:67)
    at ring.middleware.cookies$wrap_cookies$fn__30892.invoke(cookies.clj:214)
    at ring.middleware.absolute_redirects$wrap_absolute_redirects$fn__31411.invoke(absolute_redirects.clj:47)
    at ring.middleware.resource$wrap_resource_prefer_resources$fn__31309.invoke(resource.clj:25)
    at ring.middleware.content_type$wrap_content_type$fn__31359.invoke(content_type.clj:34)
    at ring.middleware.default_charset$wrap_default_charset$fn__31383.invoke(default_charset.clj:31)
    at ring.middleware.not_modified$wrap_not_modified$fn__19539.invoke(not_modified.clj:61)
    at ring.middleware.x_headers$wrap_x_header$fn__30560.invoke(x_headers.clj:22)
    at ring.middleware.x_headers$wrap_x_header$fn__30560.invoke(x_headers.clj:22)
    at ring.middleware.x_headers$wrap_x_header$fn__30560.invoke(x_headers.clj:22)
    at myapp.middleware$wrap_internal_error$fn__31485.invoke(middleware.clj:21)
    at immutant.web.internal.undertow$create_http_handler$reify__39303.handleRequest(undertow.clj:239)
    at org.projectodd.wunderboss.web.undertow.async.websocket.UndertowWebsocket$2.handleRequest(UndertowWebsocket.java:109)
    at io.undertow.server.session.SessionAttachmentHandler.handleRequest(SessionAttachmentHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:211)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:809)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Parameter Mismatch: :username parameter data not found. {}
    at hugsql.core$validate_parameters_BANG_.invokeStatic(core.clj:83)
    at hugsql.core$validate_parameters_BANG_.invoke(core.clj:69)
    at hugsql.core$prepare_sql.invokeStatic(core.clj:185)
    at hugsql.core$prepare_sql.invoke(core.clj:173)
    at hugsql.core$db_fn_STAR_$y__33452.doInvoke(core.clj:457)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:445)
    at hugsql.core$db_fn_STAR_$y__33452.invoke(core.clj:448)
    at conman.core$try_query$fn__33540$fn__33541.invoke(core.clj:30)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: do you have a stacktrace somewhere?

Comment: I think your migration is not completed. I think you ADDED username into user table.
Can you check your database via command line?

Comment: The problem was occurring before I added the username to the table. @TakuyaEbata
As for checking the DB by command line, if you tell me what you want me to check, I can do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my call to db/create-user!, within myapp.routes.home/create-user!, I had inadvertently passed an extra argument.  This was blowing up when Conman tried to do something with it.  Code and explanation in the original post.
Short answer: I counted my parentheses incorrectly. :/

Answer (score 1):

I have also run into this problem where you want the return value of an expression to be something different than the meat of the code block.  It creates  what I call a "hanging expression" problem, and is easy to misplace or overlook the last little bit of code, especially in a large `do` block (or similar such as `when`, `when-not`, etc). Even with a code formatter (like that of IntelliJ IDEA/Cursive), it isn't easy to verify the code alignment & placement of parentheses is correct.

To make code blocks like this easier to read, I created a super-simple macro [`with-result`](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.199/api/tupelo.core#with-result) in [the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).  The implementation is almost the "Hello World" for learning macros:

```
(defmacro with-result
  "Evaluates `result` and returns it; also evaluates `forms` for their side-effects."
  [result & forms]
  `(let [result# ~result]
     (do ~@forms)
     result#))
```

Using the `with-result` macro, your code would become the following:

```clj
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t]))

(defn create-user! [{:keys [params]}]
  (if-let [errors (validate-user params)]
    ; found existing user
    (-> (response/found "/users")
      (assoc :flash (assoc params :errors errors)))
    ; need to create new user
    (t/with-result (response/found "/users")
      (db/create-user!
        (assoc params
          :created_at (java.util.Date.)
          :updated_at (java.util.Date.)
          :pass (generate-password 8))))))
```

You can see I added simple comments to help set off each branch of the `if` and summarize what it does.

You could also choose to simplify a bit more by calling `(response/found ...)` in a single place:

```
(defn create-user! [{:keys [params]}]
  (let [errors   (validate-user params)
        response (response/found "/users")]
    (if errors
      (assoc response :flash (assoc params :errors errors))
      (t/with-result response
        (db/create-user!
          (assoc params
            :created_at (java.util.Date.)
            :updated_at (java.util.Date.)
            :pass (generate-password 8)))))))
```

The `with-result` is also very handy for printing the return value just prior to leaving a function, or for `core.async` code where an `core.async` channel must be returned at the end of a large code block.